# What is the difference between the permissions tags -rwxr-xr-x and -rwxrwxrwx?

Tags: permissions, interpretation

Before trying to assemble sequence data, I get a file size estimate for my raw READ1/READ2 files by running the command *ls -l -h* from the directory the files are in. The output looks something like this:

-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 catharus2021  staff    86M Jun 11 15:03 pluvialis-dominica_JJW362-READ1.fastq.gz

-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 catharus2021  staff    84M Jun 11 15:03 pluvialis-dominica_JJW362-READ2.fastq.gz

---

For a previous run using the identical command, but a different batch of data, the output was as such:

-rwxr-xr-x  1 catharus2021  staff    44M Mar 16  2018 lagopus_lagopus_alascensis_JJW1970_READ1.fastq.gz

-rwxr-xr-x  1 catharus2021  staff    52M Mar 16  2018 lagopus_lagopus_alascensis_JJW1970_READ2.fastq.gz

---

It doesn't seem to be affecting any downstream commands, but does anyone know why the strings at the very beginning (-rwxrwxrx@ vs. -rwxr-xr-x) are different? I assume that they're permissions flags, but google has been less-than-informative when I try to type those in and search.

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The coding describes who can access a file in which way. It is oredred:
owner - group - world
rwxr-xr-x
user can read, write and execute
group can only read and execute
world can only read and execute

This prevents that other people can overwrite your data. If you change to
rwxrwxrwx
Everybody can overwrite your data.

Comment: Does the @ symbol at the end of the first set of outputs mean anything? Thanks, by the way.

Comment: Normally after the @ this is a computer name. Could be permissions change depending on which computer you log in. Frequently this is done for root. (For security reasons yoou might not want root access from remote)

Comment: what is the second r in rwxr? Wouldnt rwx already describe Read, Write, Execute?

Edit: for those wondering the same "rwxr-xr-x" is "rwx | r-x | r-x". It makes a whole lot of sense when I see it that way